# Windows Task Scheduler task start failed

Tags: batch-file, server, task, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am getting an error message in Windows Task Scheduler on the server. The error value 2147944309.  The Windows Task Scheduler task start failed. There was a launch failure. This task runs everyday at 8AM ET. This task runs a bat file on the server. The task ran successfully yesterday but un-successfully today. The error says below.

```
Task Scheduler failed to start "\Tomcat Service Restart" task for the user "DOMAIN\server_user_id". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944309.
```

I do see SensorFramework-LogonTask ran today at 1:30PM.
Usually this task runs successfully.
What could have caused this issue to occur?

Comment: If this usually works, then your question has nothing to do with your programming code, but your system(s). It is therefore off topic for this platform.

Comment: the batch file code works and I am trying to figure out why the task failed.

Comment: Exactly! This site is for fixing problematic code, so please delete your off topic question, and post it to a more suitable platform.

Comment: you can try asking on superuser.com

Comment: also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/799572/scheduled-task-launch-failure-2147944309) suggests it might be active directory connected, there are def some articles on the internet you can check out, just search for "error value 2147944309 task scheduler"